# Фильтрация постов по произвольному полю

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте! Необходимо отфильтровать посты с помощью произвольного поля `cp_sys_total_ad_cost` по убыванию:

```
$args = array(
'numberposts' => 10,
'order'       => 'DESC',
'include'     => array(),
'exclude'     => array(),
'meta_key'    => 'cp_sys_total_ad_cost',
'post_type'   => 'ad_listing',
'suppress_filters' => true, 
);
```

Но, к сожалению, не работает, а выдает фильтрацию только по дате

Answer (score 1):

Так должно работать

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 10,
    'post_type'   => 'ad_listing',
    'suppress_filters' => true, 
    'meta_query' => array(
        'meta_cost' => array(
            'key'     => 'cp_sys_total_ad_cost',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_cost',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    );
```

Comment: еще оказывается проблема в том что я получал посты так  `$posts = get_posts($args);` и выводил `foreach ($posts as $post) {...` Но объект, к сожалению, не содержит производственные поля( Т.е. объект не содержит `cp_sys_total_ad_cost`

Comment: Значение произвольного поля надо получать через get_post_meta()

Comment: сделал, но чуть по другому. У меня получилось два цикла, сначала вывожу то что должно быть сверху, а потом все остальное (аналог прикрепленных записей). Теперь проблема в пагинации) Можете что-то подсказать по поводу этого?

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: Проблему с пагинацией следует вынести в другой вопрос, вместе с вашим кодом